# Does the transactionManager close the statement atuomatically?

Tags: spring, aop

Now we are using spring transactionManager to manager the DB transaction. Since we use a connection pool to hold all the connections, the connection will not be closed.
I wonder if the opended statement will be closed automatically after the transaction get failed and rollback?

Answer (score 1):

We are using C3p in our project to maintain Connection pool. We have a configuration in it to close the connection after a transaction completes.

```
<prop key="connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
```

So which transaction manager are you using?

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. You should always explicitely close your statements, and do it in finally blocks. Or use Spring's JdbcTemplate which handles this for you.